# Export map as image with selected feature color change QGIS 3.2.0

Tags: qgis

I changed the color of selected features from the default yellow, to red. However, when I export my map as a png, the color is changed back to yellow. How can I export to an image while keeping the color change of the selected features?

Comment: I tried it on my 3.2.3 installation and it also exports the image with selected features in yellow. It's probably a minor bug.